Angular Redux creating memory leaks
My angular application has to load updates from the backend 20 messages/sec. For this, we load all entities (Assets) from the backend as a snapshot at the start and then get incremental updates say 20 messages/sec. All assets are stored in a redux store and we use ngrx actions/effects to get data and update the store from the backend service (LoadAssetByIdAction is used by the effect to call the backend and LoadAssetByIdSucessAction updates the store upon receiving data).
As shown in the image, at the start we have only a very low count of objects and the memory the app is using is low (26MB). However, if I keep this for a while memory ballons to 76MB and there is a huge amount of objects retained in the memory. If this is left overnight browser tap crashes.
My question is why is this happening and is there a way to resolve this issue?


Hard to say without seeing any code or better an example.
But, AFAIK NgRx doesn't have a leak. Also be sure to disable the redux devtools, as this holds objects in memory in order to create a replayable history.
